# How to access properties of a user control using C#

Tags: c#, user-controls

I've made a `C#` user control with one `textbox`.

How can I access the property of **read only** from outside the user control.
thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411316/how-to-access-properties-of-a-usercontrol-in-c-sharp?rq=1

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I'll attempt to answer the same way you're asking ... You can access the property very easy.

Answer (score 2):

expose your textbox as a public property in the userControl and access it wherever you have used the usercontrol.

for example:

```
public class MyUserControl : UserControl
    {
           public TextBox MyTextBox 
           {
               get
               {
                  return txtBox1;
               }
               set
               {
                   txtBox1 = value;
               } 
           }
    }
```

and to make it readonly do this:

```
myUserControl.MyTextBox.ReadOnly=true; //where myUserControl is instance of 
                                       //MyUserControl, you have used somewhere
```