# how to make read only property available in my usercontrol

Tags: c#, user-controls

i make user control from 3 text boxes but i don not how to declare read only property to it i tried many things but it do not work here is my code to make the control

i want to make it read only when needed like if i add checkbox i want if checkbox.check=true make my control readonly

```
 public partial class dateIN : UserControl
    {
        Dates datess = new Dates();
        public dateIN()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void dateIN_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtDay.Text != "" || txtMonth.Text != "" || txtYear.Text != "")
            {
                if (!datess.IsHijri(txtDay.Text.Trim() + "/" + txtMonth.Text.Trim() + "/" + txtYear.Text.Trim()))
                {
                    txtDay.Focus();
                }
            }
        }
        public string Day
        {
            set { txtDay.Text = value; }
            get { return txtDay.Text; }
        }
        public string Month
        {
            set { txtMonth.Text = value; }
            get { return txtMonth.Text; }
        }
        public string Year
        {
            set { txtYear.Text = value; }
            get { return txtYear.Text; }
        }
```

need to know how to make read only property available here plz

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access properties of a user control using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787239/how-to-access-properties-of-a-user-control-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

just remove the `set { }` part of the property

Example:

```
public string Day
{
   get { return txtDay.Text; }
}
```

Comment: ted u miss understand me i want to make it read only in some cases only ex : add check box on  the form & if checkbox.checked = true i want my control to be aread only control

Answer (score 0):

I dont know the correlation of where your "txtDay", "txtMonth", "txtYear" come from, but you could do something like

```
public partial class dateIN : UserControl
{
   ...
   ...

   private bool AllowEditing()
   { return SomeCondition when SHOULD be allowed...; }


   public string Day
   {
      // only allow the set to apply the change if the "AllowEditing" condition
      // is true, otherwise, ignore the attempt to assign.
      set { if( AllowEditing() )
               txtDay.Text = value; }
      get { return txtDay.Text; }
   }

   // same concept for month and year too
}
```

Answer (score -1):

so may you add some flag to your set when it is true then you set a value.
also you can work with textbox property called ReadOnly.